# "adb shell am start -S -W PackageName/.MainActivity" command not showing time outputs?

Tags: android, performance, shell, adb

I ran the following command in my terminal.

```
adb shell am start -S -W PackageName/.MainActivity
```

But，there is no output of time as expected.
[image]